# Regex expression to exclude spaces and return numbers only

Tags: regex

At the risk of being downvoted again, I need to ask another fairly basic regex question.  I am trying to extract the number `8976` from the following string:

```
1 / 8976             RT110539
```

The number that I am trying to grab in this example is 4-digits long, but sometimes it could be only 1-digit or as many as 6-digits. This is the regex that I have created so far:

```
[/](.){6}
```

This works, but only partially because it is returning the forward slash and spaces `/ 8976` , but I only want to grab the number itself.  How should I modify this regex to return the number only, following the forward slash?  Thanks.

Comment: `(?<=\/ )\d{1,6}\b` or `\/\s*\K\d{1,6}\b`

Comment: Thanks @AvinashRaj, I really need to spend some time to learn regex a little better.  This is powerful stuff indeed, once you get the hang of it.

Comment: Quick question @AvinashRaj, can you tell me why your 2nd suggestion returns "No Match" when I test it here http://regexr.com/3bkhn ?

Comment: I think just `\s\K\d+` should work: _https://regex101.com/r/dB1wU8/1_

Comment: @DanielAttard https://regex101.com/r/dB1wU8/2 works, it won't work for you because you're runnning a lang other than perl or php. Consider adding the relevant lang tag at first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
(?<=\/)\s*(\d{1,6})
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/sB6dR6/1)

Comment: If you want to use capturing group then what's the need for lookbehind?

Comment: @AvinashRaj , yeah can just make it `\/\s*(\d{1,6})` :)