# Pure RegEx remove spaces

Tags: regex

I have a document processing application that is solely configured via XML. I can specify a search regex to find something on an image and return it if found. For example, to find an invoice number with 6 digits, I ask for [\d]{6} and it returns the number. Really straight forward. However, I have one particular invoice number where the 6 digits are spaced apart ('1 2 3 4 5 6').

`[\d\s]{6,12}` picks up the string with the spaces. If I don't look for the spaces, it doesn't match, so it doesn't return anything. Freespacing also doesn't return anything.

I've read and tried some of the other responses [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16267488/regex-remove-space) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32119008/regex-expression-to-exclude-spaces-and-return-numbers-only), but those suggestions did not work. I also can't write any replace since I don't have access to the code.

Isn't there a simple way to search and replace in the same regex? (I know... it's a **search**, so by definition, it matches to what it finds... just running out of ideas)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: that regex can match a string with 2 digit with a 4 to 10 space in between :0

Comment: Something like `(\d\s?){6}`?

Comment: Thanks @sideroxylon, but that doesn't seem to take the spaces out. It returns the string as '1 2 3 4 5 6'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Quote:** `[\d\s]{6,12}` picks up the string with the spaces. If I don't look for the spaces, it doesn't match, so it doesn't return anything. Freespacing also doesn't return anything.

Be careful, that is **not** what this is designed to do and only coincidence that it is working here. You may also get unexpective matches, like 12 spaces, 12 digits, 4 digits and 2 spaces, 3 digits and 6 spaces. `{6` is the lower bound of the quantifier's range and `12}` is the upper bound. `\s` also includes any space character so various newines, form feeds, and tabs can be your string.

`Freespacing` is something else entirely which only makes whitespace characters irrelevant in your regex so that you can write in a more readable format.

Without knowing more, the best regex to find your match may be this, because it is quite clear to read. You'll want `freespacing` off for this.

- `(?:(\d) (\d) (\d) (\d) (\d) (\d))` like [this](https://regex101.com/r/m9lLqR/4) referencing the groups `$1$2$3$4$5$6`

  - For just searching, you can do `\d \d \d \d \d \d`
- Or with freespacing `(?:(\d)[ ](\d)[ ](\d)[ ](\d)[ ](\d)[ ](\d))`

`(\d\s){6}` will also match your pattern--if there's a trailing space, where `\s` is, depending on the flavor, almost any `whitespace` character (parentheses for grouping, rather than square brackets for character class), but is not suitable for replace operation.

Even `(\d\s?){6}`, as referenced in the comments has the flaw of permitting 6 digit strings (`235211` for instance), even if no spaces are present. This is because `?` in this instance means `0 or 1 times, as many times as possible`. So grab it if it's there, and ignore it if it's not. Given the design of the source, this regex may work as a simple find solution `(?:\d\s(?:\s|$))` where `(?:\s|$)` means `whitespace character, or if that's not present end of string/line` depending on flags.